# Conditional Expectation and identically independent distributed random variables.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

I have a problem that can be resolved if i show that
$$E(\varepsilon_k\mid\sigma(\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_{k-1}))=E(\varepsilon_k)$$
where $\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k$ $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and i know they are independent.

I dont know where to even start. Any proof or help would be great.

Comment: If $X$ is integrable and independent of $Y$ then $E[X\mid Y]=E(X)$.

Comment: use the definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: Davide Giraudo: Is that not what i want to show?
@NateEldredge:
The Definition of conditional expectation is the real-valued random variable satisfying that
$$
\int_D X dP = \int_D E(X| \mathbb{D}) dP 
 $$
for every $D \in \mathbb{D}$.
Can you give me a Hint on how to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of conditional expectation, it suffices to show
$\int_D \varepsilon_k \,dP = \int_D E[\varepsilon_k]\,dP$ for every $D \in \sigma(\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_{k-1})$.  In other words, to show that
$E[1_D \varepsilon_k] = E[1_D] E[\varepsilon_k]$.  But what do you know about the random variables $\varepsilon_k$ and $1_D$?